# Как вводить в переменную большой текст, более 255 символов?

Tags: pascal

Задан текст, заканчивающийся точкой. Слова в тексте разделены одним или несколькими пробелами. Определить количество слов, начинающихся с заданной буквы. Без использования типа String и массивов. Тогда как?

Comment: А изначально как задан текст?

Comment: Попробуйте создать свой тип, хотя я не знаю. Проще всего было бы использовать `char[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то такое, JS:

```
function calc( str, ch ){
  var i,
      res = 0;

  if ( str[0] == ch ) res++; 
  for ( i = 1; i < str.length; i++ ){
    if ( ( str[i] == ch ) && ( str[i-1] == ' ' ) ) res++;
  }

  return res;
}

var str = 'Задан текст заканчивающийся точкой Слова в тексте разделены одним или несколькими пробелами Определить количество слов начинающихся с заданной буквы Без использования типа String и массивов Тогда как.';
alert( calc( str, 'т' ) );
```

Что-бы не использовать строки - читаем посимвольно, храня текущий и предыдущий символы.

Comment: Но строка то у вас есть:)

Comment: > Что-бы не использовать строки - читаем посимвольно
Где тут есть строка?

Comment: А посимвольно вы не строку читаете?

Comment: Посимвольно читается файловый поток/буфер клавиатуры.

Answer (score 2):

Тогда используй тип `PChar`.

Comment: Согласен. PChar это и не строка и не массив - это ссылка на область памяти!

Answer (score 2):

ребят, не издевайтесь над человеком)
Задача: найти кол-во слов, начинающихся с данной буквы.
Вообще у [[@timka_s](/users/1192/timka_s)](/users/1192/timka_s) ответ верный. Паскаль:

```
/* модуль */
uses crt;
/* переменные */
var ch, ourChar: char;
    pass: boolean;
    words: integer;

/* код */
pass := false; // не пропускаем буквы
ourChar := 'К'; // искомая буква
words := 0; 
repeat
  ch := readkey;
  if ( ch = ' ' ) then begin // если пробел - следом идет новое слово
    pass := false;
    continue;
    end
  else if not ( pass ) then begin // если буква - первая и она равна нашей - слова++ и пропускаем до конца слова или точки
    if (ch = ourChar) then
      inc(words);
    pass := true;
    end;
  until ch = '.';
writeln('---');
write('Слов: ');
writeln(words);
readln;
```

Сразу говорю - не тестил. Пробуйте, будут трудные ошибки - покопаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Так и просится в вашем случае или список или дерево. В сей структуре вы будете хранить первую букву слова (судя по заданию этого достаточно) и количество вхождений.

Каждый раз, когда встречается новая буква, вы ее добавляете в дерево (список), если такая буква уже есть - увеличиваете счетчик.

Comment: Ни список, ни дерево тут ни к месту. Начальная буква уже задана.

Comment: и что? вопрос сводится, как хранить строку, вот я и предложил в список, а для оптимизации алгоритма - в дерево и по начальной букве. А если буква не известна? Предлагайте свой вариант, который по-вашему мнению больше к месту

Comment: В тексте вопроса сказано "начинающихся с заданной буквы". каким местом тут "а если буква не известна"?
Вариант могу предложить, только сначала скажите, как именно задан текст. обычно в таких заданиях из учебника это файл.

Comment: А таким, что букву можно вводить с клавиатуры как до, так и после считывания данных из того же файла. Кроме того, в вопросе явно звучит "в переменную большой текст".

Comment: Читаем посимвольно до точки. Опрределяем символ - это разделитель (пробел, запятая и т.п.) или нет. Если предыдущий символ был разделителем, а текущий это **заданная буква**, то **увеличиваем счетчик**. 

Хранить вообще никаких слов не надо. Списки и проч. напрочь не нужны.

Comment: @avp, логично, но вопрос есть вопрос, из басни слов не выкинешь, что если человеку надо сперва считать, затем ввести букву, и только лишь после производить поиск?

Comment: Я понял вопрос так, что текста в программе нет. Иначе надо говорить, как он в ней представлен. О том, что текст надо сохранять в вопросе нет ни слова.

Comment: "Как в Pascal вводить в переменную большой текст, более 255 символов?" видимо это мне одному кажется?

Comment: Заголовок вопроса об этом, а текст о другом. 

Кстати, я случайно на него кликнул (я вообще не знал о таком ограничении в Pascal) прочел текст и написал, как делать независимо от языка.